# Ошибка error LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Написал программу которая берет данные с сайта и выводит их в DataGridView, все работает когда одна форма. Но когда я добавил вторую форму, чтобы открывалось в ней повылазили ошибки:

Типа: Ошибка    error LNK2005

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы гениально продемонстрировали, как НЕ надо задавать вопросы. Никакой полезной информации, не совсем соответствующий тэг, не указан даже компилятор, вывалена вся куча ваших файлов...

Судя по тому, что такое ошибка [LNK2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/72zdcz6f.aspx), вы ухитрились, например, дважды описать одну и ту же функцию - добавляя эту вторую форму. У вас в результате есть две функции с одним и тем же именем, и линковщик не знает, какую выбрать.

Вот официальное мнение MS :), почему такое происходит и что делать. Позвольте и мне задать вам вопрос: что здесь было непонятно для вас? 
(Потому что поверить в то, что человек не попытался разобраться с проблемой сам, и не искал решение на официальном сайте компилятора, а понесся сразу на SO - просто не могу. Программисты так не поступают :))

Итак:

1. Смешивание статических и динамических библиотек при одновременном использовании /clr.
2. Символ является упакованной функцией (созданной путем компилирования с параметром /Gy) и был включен более чем в один файл, но изменен в промежутке между компиляциями.  Перекомпилируйте все файлы, включающие symbol.
3. Символ определен по-разному в двух объектах-членах в различных библиотеках, и оба объекта-члена используются.
4. Абсолютное значение определено дважды с различными значениями.
5. Файл заголовка объявлен и определен как переменная.  Ниже представлены возможные решения.

   Объявите переменную в H-файле: extern BOOL MyBool;, а затем присвойте ей значение в C-файле или CPP-файле: BOOL MyBool = FALSE;.

   Объявите переменную как static.

   Объявите переменную как selectany.
6. Вы используете uuid.lib в сочетании с другими файлами LIB, определяющими идентификаторы GUID (например oledb.lib и adsiid.lib).

Comment: Я еще только учусь)) Помогло: Объявить переменную как static. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Не уверен, откровенно говоря. Боюсь, что это могло просто скрыть симптом, а не решить проблему. Но и копаться в вашем проекте, простите - времени столько нет...

Comment: @Harry, думаю вполне могло помочь. Если в файлах обеих форм объявлялась одна глобальная переменная, то после добавления static стало две переменных, каждая из которых видима только в своём файле. В принципе, это решение, хотя и костыльное.