# "Возникли ошибки сборки. Продолжить и запустить последний успешно построенный вариант?"

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-studio-2015

1) Visual Studio. С++. ООП. Как исправить ошибку, возникающую при попытке запустить код? См. заголовок.

2) Ещё возникают ошибки LNK2005.

3) Ещё в списке ошибок часть пояснений написана кракозябрами.

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить эти три проблемы.

Comment: Вы должны исправить ошибки в своём коде, разумеется. Ваш код не компилируется, прочитайте сообщения компилятора и убедитесь, что вы их понимаете.

Comment: покажите кракозябры

Comment: Ни кто не может помочь вам "исправить проблемы" не видя самих проблем. Где сообщения об ошибках компиляции? Где код, вызвавший эти ошибки?

Comment: По второму вопросу - ну, см., например, тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584844/195342 А вообще - что может сказать доктор на жалобу, например "у меня болит живот"? Заочно спасать от гастрита, отравления, аппендицита или приступа холецистита? попробуй угадай при отсутствии симптомов...

Comment: Это сложно объяснить, проще скинуть проект.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5M5b/19xfh6Uyn

Comment: Не, весь проект — это как-то слишком много. Попробуйте соорудить [mcve]

Comment: Мне очень полезна ваша ссылка, когда сдам сессию, почитаю через недельку. Не знаю знаю как тут вставить картинку, первый раз на этом форуме. Ну хотя бы так https://cloud.mail.ru/public/G3yb/mpYdBqWfd Это ошибка 1) в моем списке. При нажатии на иконку панели инструментов "Локальный отладчик windows", чтобы выполнить текст, возникает ошибка. Посмотрите фото по ссылке.

Comment: Ошибка 3) кракозябры. Выделены на фото красной рамкой. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/MsmM/foqXiFpX9

Comment: Ошибка 2) Как исправить ошибку LNK2005 https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Kbrt/YVs9uAYbH

Comment: @Igor cloud.mail.ru/public/MsmM/foqXiFpX9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрев ваш проект, сообщаю: вы компилируете файлы `Unit.cpp` и `Source.cpp`. И все бы ничего, на вы же ухитрились в `Unit.cpp` внести строку

```
#include "Source.cpp"
```

так что все функции и иже с ними, имеющиеся в `Source.cpp`, **скомпилированы дважды**! Уберите эту строку.

И как только вы сделаете это и добавите отсутствующие у вас реализации `Employee::Print()` и `Housewives::Print()`, все соберется. Заработает ли - это уже совсем второй вопрос, я не смотрел сам код, только сборку...

Comment: спасибо) попробую применить

Comment: Если получится (а оно получится :)) - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый.

Comment: хорошо, так и сделаю